# Asus X550D-XX090H has low frame rates playing League of Legends

Tags: laptop, memory

I have the following laptop:

- Asus X550D-XX090H
- Windows 8
- Processor: AMD A10-5750M APU with (Radeon HD 8670M 2GB) graphics 2.50 GHz
- RAM: 4.00 GB (3.21 GB usable)
- System type: 64-bit Operating system, x64-based processor
- 1 TB HDD

I just bought this laptop last week (Sept. 28 2014) and downloaded League of Legends. My FPS during gaming is 1–8.

Is that normal? What could I do to achieve higher frame rates?

Answer (score 1):

Well League of Legends is surprisingly pretty demanding for video. It is possible that your built in video card isn't beafy enough. Also if your laptop gets really hot after playing for some time you may want to invest in one of those laptop cooling pads.  If it is not a heat problem then getting an SSD could possibly help some too since replacing a video card in a laptop isn't practical.